# React: How does one access a phone's actual camera app (not load feed in browser)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've come across quite a few packages and APIs for opening a stream and capturing images, but all of these solutions entail loading the feed in a component, so the 'camera' is an in-browser utility. Is there a way to open the phone's actual camera app outside the DOM?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/capturing-images: `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>` (then use FileReader in the usual way to read the file input)

Comment: Wow, the solution is so simple I completely missed it. Embarrassing, but thanks! :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="environment">
```

Modern phone browsers can opt to use the camera app as input for `<input type="file">` input, in lieu of a file-selection dialog, when you use the property `accept="image/*"`. This will allow users to select their preferred input, but if you use the property `capture` on the input element, the browser sees a hint to automatically use the camera without giving a choice at all. [`capture` can have a value as well](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/capturing-images), to hint which camera should be used:

> Adding the `capture` attribute without a value let's the browser decide which camera to use, while the `"user"` and `"environment"` values tell the browser to prefer the front and rear cameras, respectively.
>
> The `capture` attribute works on Android and iOS, but is ignored on desktop. Be aware, however, that on Android this means that the user will no longer have the option of choosing an existing picture. The system camera app will be started directly, instead.

Once you have an input image, you can read it as you would any input file, e.g., with `FileReader`.

Comment: Very nice and clean solution!

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to @apsillers for the answer. Here's a React-specific implementation for those who are trying to create a button that prompts *actual* camera load for photo-taking and not a video feed capture in-browser:

The button:

```
<div >
  <label>
    <input 
      style={{display: 'none'}} 
      type='file' 
      accept="image/*"
      capture="environment"
      onChange={this.handleImageChange}
     />
    <YourCustomButton/>
  </label>
</div>
```

Handler:

```
handleImageChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({
    image: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @apsillers and @struensee for the answers, I managed to do what I was looking for with both answers. However, there was something missing on @struensee answer, and I would like to contribute with my **React solution**:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

const UploadImageComponent = () => {
  const [imageObject, setImageObject] = useState(null);

  const handleFileInput = useRef(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
    handleFileInput.current.click();
  };

  const handleImageChange = (event) => {
    setImageObject({
      imagePreview: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]),
      imageFile: event.target.files[0],
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Upload Photo</button>
      <label>
        <input
          style={{ display: "none" }}
          type="file"
          accept="image/*"
          capture="environment"
          ref={handleFileInput}
          onChange={handleImageChange}
        />
      </label>
      {imageObject && <img src={imageObject.imagePreview} />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default UploadImageComponent;
```

The use of ref will ensure clicking on the button will trigger the onChange in the hidden input. The `<img>` tag is there to display the image currently being uploaded.

Comment: The question was not about uploading an image, but it was accessing phone camera app and capturing one.